# SwiftUI Navigation between Parent and Child Lists Views causes extra refresh on device but not in Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI application that has a Parent View with a Navigation View and a List with several items. When clicking on any one item in the list the app navigates to the Child View which also has a simple List with some items.

The problem is that in the simulator everything is fine, the navigation is fluid and crisp but when I run the code on my phone there is a visible refresh when the child view loads, the refresh is very subtle but still visible, you can actually see the top most list item separator appear and the list jiggles a little.

I have been able to reproduce this even with this simple code below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var numbers = ["1","2","3"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(self.numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                NavigationLink(destination: ChildView()) {
                    Text(number)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Parent"))
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    var numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]

    var body: some View {
        List(self.numbers, id: \.self) { number in
          Text(number)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Child"))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here is the screen recording of the code above when running on my iPhone. Notice the child list view and how it jiggles a bit, the first list item separator is not even present during the transition, it appears after the refresh.

How can I fix this?? The code above seems also straight forward so I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for your help.

[image: SwiftUI Navigation refresh issue]